# Java comparing row of list to list

Tags: java

I have a sql output with 2 columns (userID, projectID). There are multiple entries and no entries are empty or null.

I want to generate a list for network modelling that contains 2 columns (userID, userID) where 2 users are listed together if they share a `projectID`, for example

**Input**

```
userID   projectID
  1         201
  1         502
  2         502
  2         101
  3         201
  3         502
```

**Output**

```
userID   userID
  1         2
  1         3
  2         3
```

Essentially I want a SQL WHERE like comparison like

```
SELECT u1.userID, u2.userID
FROM user_project u1
JOIN user_project u2 ON u1.projectID = u2.projectID
```

but in in Java. The resulting tuples can be distinct or not, and order of the results does not matter. I can't directly query the database with this query as I don't have db access, only access to the output txts.

I'm thinking this could probably be done in a for-loop with a HashMap or ArrayList, but is there a more efficient way to do it? or is there a package that lets me use SQL-like commands on Java objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> or is there a package that lets me use SQL-like commands on Java objects?

Yes.  Two main libraries come to mind...

1. [querydsl.com](http://www.querydsl.com/) - Run type-safe queries on Java Collections, JPA, JDO, etc.
2. [jooq.org](http://www.jooq.org/) - Does the same

You can also use Apache Commons [CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html) library to first parse that file into the collection if you'd like something that would support multiple formats.

Comment: Yes!! querydsl looks like what I'm looking for.

Comment: Would you happen to know what type of configuration and datasource the SQLQueryFactory of querydsl uses? Documentation on SQLQueryFactory is sparse, can't find example of using java objects as datasource in SQLQueryFactory.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this result in three steps:

- Build a hash map of `ProjectID` to a list of `UserID`s
- For each list of length 2 or more make all pairs, for example, with two nested loops
- Eliminate duplicate pairs from the result

The third step can be combined with the second step if you use a collection that eliminates duplicates, such as a `Set`.

This would be as efficient as it gets in terms of performance, because all searches would be done in amortized O(1).

Comment: So for each userID generate a list of projectID they are associated with. For each list, compare each projectID in list against other userID list to get distinct pairs. I got that bit, but how is running time O(1)? If I loop through a list of n items, looking for pairs also looks through n pairs. So wouldn't running time be at least O(n^2)?

Comment: @user1931007 It's the other way around: for each project ID, generate a list of user IDs. If you use hash map of id to list of ids, each element of the input would be processed in amortized O(1), so the whole list would be processed in amortized linear time.

Answer (score 0):

1) 
create a HashMap with projectID as KEY and Ordered LinkedList of UserID as values.
    Example :

```
 PROJECT_ID                    USERID
  201                           1 => 3
  502                           1 => 2 => 3
```

2) 
once your HashMap is built as above, then you can iterate through all the entries in HashMap one by one and can print the required output. 
since the linked list we have created is ordered, you can again iterate through the linked list and print the output in requird order.

3) 
you can store the result as String say "12" , "13", "23" and can either sort them and remove duplicate entries.

Comment: How did you manage step 1? Meaning how did you derive the LinkedList of UserID. I tried used indexOf but that only returns first entry, so I'm going to have to iterate through all rows.

Comment: you need to create an linkedlist of values for each key. example HashMap map = new HashMap<Integer,LinkedList<Integer>>(); say if user 1 and 2 have same projectID 501, you will b indexing with projectid and they will be goin into the same index in the hashmap, while adding the userId as value to the list, you have to traverse the list and add it at appropriate position to maintain the order.

Comment: Ah so I still need to be looping over rows to find the matching userID or projectID. I was looking to see if there was a better way to traverse the data rather than double iterations (messy to code and could have large runtime over large dataset using nested iteration).